# Invalid option in build() call: "watch"

Tags: configuration, esbuild

I am following the example as it is described here:

https://bilalbudhani.com/chokidar-esbuild/

When I do:

```
node esbuild.config.js --watch
```

I get the message:

```
[ERROR] Invalid option in build() call: "watch"
```

I have no idea why this is happening.

Is "watch" not longer a parameter?

I also did this example:

```
const path = require('path')

require("esbuild").build({
  entryPoints: ["application.js", "client.js"],
  bundle: true,
  sourcemap: true,
  outdir: path.join(process.cwd(), "app/assets/builds"),
  absWorkingDir: path.join(process.cwd(), "app/javascript"),
  minify: true,
  watch: true,
})
.then(() => console.log("⚡Done"))
.catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

If i remove the line "watch:true", it compiles ok. But if I leave it, I get the same error:

Invalid option in build() call: "watch"

when I do: node esbuild.config.js

Comment: Which esbuild version you're using? v0.17 change quite a bit recently and docs are not up to date yet. Try with latest v0.16

Comment: You might be interested that esbuild now supports `serve` combined with `watch`. See https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#0170

Comment: @Fabian I get now. From 0.17.4 docs: "..This change removes the incremental and watch options as well as the serve() method, and introduces a new context() method...". I used esbuild 0.17.4. Downgraded to 0.16.17 and it worked! Thank you. I use rails with esbuild and started with this config: https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails/issues/8#issuecomment-962138249. Anyway, you should have replied instead of commenting so I could accept you answer. Thank you again.

Comment: By the way,  I have no idea how the esbuild.config.js should work with 0.17.4 new async api.

Comment: Someone was kind enough to provide a solution to this problem with esbuild 0.17x. See here: https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails/issues/8#issuecomment-1403699565

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Summing up from the comments:

esbuild <v0.16 has removed the `watch` option. Most tutorials and HowTos are pointing to that version. Downgrade your esbuild to that if you want to use it like described there.

Better option is to use esbuild >0.16 which has a built in [live reload](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#live-reload) which combines [watch](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#watch) and [serve](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#serve) using the newly introduced [context](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#0170)